# Scheme failed to load due to an error

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

Something wrong has happened with a small test project I'm working upon. I can't build, run, test or clean it. When I pick `Product` item in Xcode's menu the corresponding options are grayed out. If I'm trying to test it or edit the scheme, then I see the following:

Xcode 6 - [image]

Xcode 5 - [image]

What is that? Did you ever meet such an issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue before. Just add new scheme and remove the one having error.

Answer (score 11):

This error usually occurs when your .xcscheme file conflicts.Resolve the conflict and restart Xcode can be solved.

Comment: Same scenario, issue was due to the conflict. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix for me was switching to a different branch in Xcode where the scheme worked. Then I switch back to other branch and it was magically fixed.